# prepare domain list to work with squid 3.x

Tags: bash, squid

the latest version of squid do not accept duplicated domains like:

```
example.com
pre.example.com     --- this is no longer necessary
```

and it requires domains to start from "."

adding dot is simple:

```
sed -i 's/^/\./' filename_with_domain_list
```

but how to remove duplicates.?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be by running `squid -k parse`. It will tell you which line(s) are in error.

Comment: i have 20 categories and each has 50 000 lines so it does not help me.

Comment: It's not an impossible task, but you're going to have to script it. While I'm sure people here would be glad to  help you troubleshoot something you wrote, don't expect people to do all of your work for you.